# css different page orientation with one print process

Tags: html, css

I've a html page with two divs and one button.
what I want to do is when clicking on the button print the two divs. The first one in landscape orientation and the second one in portlet orientation. I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
@page { size: A5; margin: 0; }
@page:first { size: A5 landscape; margin: 0; }
```

the second div breaked into two pages as below 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYILB.png)
which it doesn't happen when using only portlet orientation.

Comment: Browser support isn't great to say the least.

Comment: You cannot do it with one print command. You have to give two separate print commands, one for landscape and second for portrait printing.